# Getting query by date - ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime

I am trying to get a sum of figures by today's date.
My approach is to use LocalDateTime formatted as below

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

And The date I am picking from the server is of this format

```
2020-03-26 12:36:14.48947
```

Since the date variation keeps changing, my interest is to deal with this **2020-03-26** as both will exist from the formatted today's date and the date from the server

Here is the query I am using

```
"... AND p.regDate LIKE :todayDate..."
```

Here is the DateTimeFormertter

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime today = null;
today = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println("here is today " + today);
```

With the approach above, I am getting an error. Please hw can I get todays date from the query

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: Also why `LocalDateTime today = null; today = LocalDateTime.now();`, why not `LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();`

Comment: Here is the error::: 
 - ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown

Comment: If I understand in your database you have regDate equal to `2020-03-26` and you want to get record which `regDate` equal to this date?

Comment: No. I have regDate equal to 2020-03-26 12:36:14.48947

Comment: and you want to filter with `2020-03-26`?

Comment: Also which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Yes. I want to achieve that so that I can easily also filter the current of LocalDateTime and make a result

Comment: I am using pgAdmin

Comment: And what you want to pass in `todayDate`

Comment: sure I want to pass in todayDate

Comment: `LIKE` is only for strings. Would you expect `LocalDateTime.now().startsWith("2020-03-26")` to work in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to a `LocalDate` not `LocalDateTime` to your query:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(); // current date "2020-03-26"
// or a custom LocalDate
LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.MARCH, 26);
```

And then, to get the date part from datetime in your databse, you can use :

```
"... AND DATE(p.regDate) = :todayDate..."
```

Where: `DATE(p.regDate)` extract only the date part, the compare with `=` not `LIKE`

Comment: On a separate attempt just trying to get a week ago record, so did this - LocalDate nextWeek = today.plus(1, ChronoUnit.WEEKS); and in the db I have this - 2020-03-19 12:36:14.48947

Comment: and the result is null

Comment: @Blaze to get Week ago `2020-03-19` you mean `LocalDate.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.WEEKS)`? Note the `minus`, not `plus`